# OWLAPI ObjectPropertyChain axioms

Tags: owl, protege, protege4

We know that in Protege is possible to create axioms with role chain and since Protege is based on OWLAPI should be possible to create them.
I did not found examples in the official documentation, so it is possible to do it?
One example here:

[image]

With the OWL syntax we have:

```
Declaration( ObjectProperty( :isEmployedAt ) )

ObjectPropertyAssertion( :isEmployedAt :Martin :SC )

SubObjectPropertyOf( ObjectPropertyChain( :isEmployedAt :isPartOf ) :isEmployedAt)
```

So, what is the equivalent in OWLAPI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
OWLDataFactory::getOWLSubPropertyChainOfAxiom(java.util.List<? extends OWLObjectPropertyExpression> chain,OWLObjectPropertyExpression superProperty)
```

See [Javadoc](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLDataFactory.html#getOWLSubPropertyChainOfAxiom(java.util.List,%20org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLObjectPropertyExpression))

Comment: Thank you. Is there also a way to return the chain in the type OWLObjectPropertyExpression?

Comment: You mean to get the chain from the axiom back?If yes, it would be `OWLSubPropertyChainOfAxiom::getPropertyChain`, see http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLSubPropertyChainOfAxiom.html

Comment: No. I mean that in my case the chain must be the first argument of getOWLObjectSomeValuesFrom(arg1, arg2). With this type I get the error because it is not compatible.

Comment: That is not possible in OWL. It can be either an object property or its inverse. Why should this be a chain?

Comment: @UninformedUser (I know this is an old post, but I'm looking at the same kind of construction...)  It can be useful to represent things like: `GrandchildOfBritishGrandmother subClassOf (hasParent o hasMother) some Briton`, for instance.  That's a case where it would be handy to be able to have the chain as an explicit thing that could be used as the first argument to `getOWLObjectSomeValuesFrom`.  Now, this *can* be represented as `GrandchildOfBritishGrandmother subClassOf (hasParent some (hasMother some Briton))`, but that's a little clumsier.